# Migrate content when upgrading to a new API Manager version?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

we are evaluating the WSO2 API Manager on Windows and noticed that there are no instructions in the official WSO2 documentation on how to upgrade or migrate user content (such as published API configuration) from one version of the product to another.

In our case we wanted to migrate from version 1.4.0 to 1.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instructions here AM-1.5.0\dbscripts\migration-1.4.0_to_1.5.0